# Matlab: Optimization problem with objective function and constraints involving summation

Tags: matrices, optimization, summation, matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve the following constrained nonlinear optimization problem using `fmincon` function in Matlab. I am finding it difficult to implement the objective function and constraints in Matlab as these involve summation.

$$
\begin{align}
\max_{v_{mn}y_{mn}} & K \sum\limits^{M}_{m=1}\sum\limits^N_{n=1} v_{mn}\mathbb{E}\left[\log_2(1+\dfrac{B_{mn}y_{mn}}{v_{mn}})\right]\\
\text{subject to:} &\sum\limits^{M}_{m=1}\sum\limits^N_{n=1} \mathbb{E}[y_{mn}] \leq W_{max},\\
&\sum\limits^M_{n=1} \sum\limits^N_{n=1} I_{n}\mathbb{E}[y_{mn}] \leq I_{\text{max}},\\
&\sum\limits^M_{m=1}v_{mn}\leq 1, \forall n\in N,\\
& y_{mn} \geq 0, \forall m\in M, n\in N,\\
&v_{mn}\geq 0,\forall m\in M, n\in N.
\end{align}
$$

I can simplify this problem by considering only one decision variable i.e. $y_{mn}$ and by dropping the expectation as under

$$
\begin{align}
\max_{y_{mn}} & K \sum\limits^{M}_{m=1}\sum\limits^N_{n=1} v_{mn}\left[\log_2(1+\dfrac{B_{mn}y_{mn}}{v_{mn}})\right]\\
\text{subject to:} &\sum\limits^{M}_{m=1}\sum\limits^N_{n=1} y_{mn} \leq W_{max},\\
&\sum\limits^M_{n=1} \sum\limits^N_{n=1} I_{n}y_{mn} \leq I_{\text{max}},\\
% &\sum\limits^M_{m=1}v_{mn}\leq 1, \forall n\in N,\\
& y_{mn} \geq 0, \forall m\in M, n\in N.
% &v_{mn}\geq 0,\forall m\in M, n\in N.
\end{align}
$$

To give a better view of the problem involved, typical values are $K=20000$, $M=3$, $N=10$ and each of $v_{mn}$, $B_{mn}$ and $y_{mn}$ are elements of matrices of size $M \times N$. These elements are fractions with values between 0 and 1. Typically, $W_{max}=1.5$ and ${I_{max}=5\times 10^{-10}}$. $I_n$ is a vector where each element is of the order of $10^{-11}$.

Now, I am trying to solve this using optimization function `fmincon` provided in Matlab with the format:

```
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

I think I can pass on the objective function, initial values of the decision variable and the constraints using the `fun`, `x0`, `A`, `b` and `lb` arguments of the above function. However, I am finding it difficult to do so as the objective function and the constraints involve summation. Can some one help to figure out the right way to do this in Matlab.

Thanks in advance.

A

Comment: Forget about the fmincon syntax and summations for the moment. You need to figure out what the expectations are.  What are you taking the expectations with respect to? For given values of the optimization (decision) variables, you need to be able to evaluate the objective function and constraints, and it's not obvious you even know what they mean.  And  $v_{mn}$, $B_{mn}$ and $y_{mn}$ are not matrices of size $M \times N$, they are scalar elements of matrices of those sizes.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone You are right about $v_{mn}$ , $B_{mn}$ and $y_{mn}$. I have edited the question to improve the description. Thanks for pointing this out. However, I would rather like to forget the expectation and  implement this in Matlab without taking expectation into consideration. We can think about adding the expectation later.

Comment: To move this to SO is not a very good option as there is not MathJax available there as far as I know. I migrated it to another site that seems well-suited to me. (I hope I am right about that.)